# Separate arrays inside objects to single objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, post

I'm trying to create 2 different objects from arrays inside an object.

I have made a table which passes all the data via POST method.

For example, this is what the form sends when I add data to 2 rows:

[image]

```
{ fm_tipo_comp_select: [ '1', '3' ],
  fm_tipo_gasto: [ '1', '6' ],
  fm_serie: [ '1234', '4321' ],
  fm_ndoc: [ '11551151', '222111' ],
  fm_ruc: [ '74111', '17144151658' ],
  fm_fecha: [ 'May 16, 2019', 'May 25, 2019' ],
  fm_moneda: [ '2', '5' ],
  fm_retencion: [ '16', '16' ] }
```

I need to separate it like this:

Object 1

```
{ fm_tipo_comp_select: '1',
  fm_tipo_gasto: '1',
  fm_serie: '1234',
  fm_ndoc: '11551151',
  fm_ruc: '74111',
  fm_fecha: 'May 16, 2019',
  fm_moneda: '2',
  fm_retencion: '16' }
```

Object 2

```
{ fm_tipo_comp_select: '3',
      fm_tipo_gasto: '6',
      fm_serie: '4321',
      fm_ndoc: '222111',
      fm_ruc: '17144151658',
      fm_fecha: 'May 25, 2019',
      fm_moneda: '5',
      fm_retencion: '16' }
```

How can I separate my object like that, or better how do I send a form with the objects separated.

I'm using nodejs.

**---- EDIT ----**

This is my form:

```
form#fm-form.col.s12(method='POST', action='/facturas/m/add')
                .row
                    a.btn-floating.btn-small.waves-effect.waves-light.green.add-btn
                        i.material-icons add
                    table#fm-table
                        thead
                            tr
                                th Tipo de Comprobante
                                th Tipo de Gasto
                                th Serie
                                th N° Documento
                                th RUC
                                th Razón Social
                                th Fecha
                                th Moneda
                                th Monto
                                th Cod. Retención
                                th Eliminar

                        tbody
                            tr
                                td 
                                    .inputfield
                                        select(name='fm_tipo_comp_select')
                                            option(value='', disabled='', selected='') Comprobante
                                            each row in tipo_comprobante
                                                option(value=row.tipo_comprobante_id) #{row.tipo_comprobante_name}    
                                        label Tipo comprobante
                                td 
                                    .inputfield
                                        select(name='fm_tipo_gasto')
                                            option(value='', disabled='', selected='') Tipo gasto
                                            each row in tipo_gasto
                                                option(value=row.tipo_gasto_id) #{row.tipo_gasto_name}
                                        label Tipo gasto
                                td 
                                    .inputfield
                                        input#fm_serie.validate.right-align(type='text', name='fm_serie')
                                td 
                                    .inputfield
                                        input#fm_ndoc.validate.right-align(type='text', name='fm_ndoc')
                                td 
                                    .inputfield
                                        input#fm_ruc.validate.right-align(type='text', name='fm_ruc')
                                td 
                                    .inputfield
                                        input#fm_rs.validate.right-align(type='text', name='fm_rs'  disabled)
                                td 
                                    .inputfield
                                        input#fm_fecha.datepicker.validate(type='text', name='fm_fecha')
                                td 
                                    .inputfield
                                        select(name='fm_moneda')
                                            option(value='', disabled='', selected='') Moneda
                                            each row in currency
                                                option(value=row.currency_id) #{row.currency_name}
                                        label Moneda
                                td 
                                    .inputfield
                                        input#fm_monto.validate(type='number')
                                td 
                                    .inputfield
                                        select(name='fm_retencion')
                                            option(value='', disabled='', selected='') Retención
                                            each row in rendiciones
                                                option(value=row.rendicion_id) #{row.rendicion_name}
                                        label Retención
                                td
                                    .inputfield
                                        a.btn-floating.btn-small.waves-effect.waves-light.red.delete-btn
                                            i.material-icons delete

                .row.fm_buttons_row
                    .input-field.col.s4
                        button.btn.waves-effect.waves-light.red(type='submit', name='action')
                            | Cancelar
                            i.material-icons.right cancel
                    .input-field.col.s4
                        button.btn.waves-effect.waves-light(type='submit', name='action')
                            | Guardar
                            i.material-icons.right save
                    .input-field.col.s4
                        button.btn.waves-effect.waves-light(type='submit', name='action')
                            | Enviar
                            i.material-icons.right send
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take for each item an own object for the result set.

```js
var data = { fm_tipo_comp_select: ['1', '3'], fm_tipo_gasto: ['1', '6'], fm_serie: ['1234', '4321'], fm_ndoc: ['11551151', '222111'], fm_ruc: ['74111', '17144151658'], fm_fecha: ['May 16, 2019', 'May 25, 2019'], fm_moneda: ['2', '5'], fm_retencion: ['16', '16'] },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => a.map((v, i) => Object.assign({}, r[i], { [k]: v })), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How can I add the `result` code, because I'm receiving the object from a form. I tried adding it as a property and as a extra var but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you write the extended function?

Comment: what do you mean with *extended*?

Comment: I understand now. I meant like now I know that the `=>` is a function

Comment: It also says that a.map is not  a function.

Comment: Could you help me with your solution? It says a.map is not a function.

Comment: do you have not arrays as values?

Comment: Worked. For some reason, there was a property which was not an array and that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ...or better how do I send a form with the objects separated.

Instead of pushing the values as array, use a separate object for each row then push that into an array like this:

```
let row1= {
a: 1,
b: 2,
}

let row2 = {
a: 3,
b: 4,
}

let data = [row1, row2];
```

Comment: How would you post that from the form?

Comment: On front-end are you using react or anything else?

May I see the code where you are using a post method?

Comment: Any ideas on how to send data from form?